# All possible ways to put data in request body

Tags: java, http, httprequest, apache-httpclient-4.x

In our system we have integration with another one.

However, we feel stuck at calling some API method called `api/esia/verify`

Here's a screen from swagger with required header and body content

[image]

I've tried to put password into the body like that:

1. As a plain entity
2. As MultipartEntity
3. As JSON object

All like below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

The code is as follows:

```
public static boolean finishAuthorization(final String bearerToken, final String password) throws IOException 
    {       
        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        try
        {
            HttpPut httpPut = new HttpPut("urlToSendTo");
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(password); // first case
            /* MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
            builder.addTextBody("password", password);
            HttpEntity entity = builder.build();
            httpPut.setEntity(entity); */ // second case
            /* StringEntity se = new StringEntity(new JSONObject().put("password", password).toString()); */ // third case

            httpPut.setEntity(se);

            EGRZHttpUtils.addHeadersToHttp(httpPut, new HashMap<String, String>(){{
                put("Authorization", bearerToken);
                put("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
            }});

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPut);
            System.out.println("response status " +  response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
            return Boolean.valueOf(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
        }
        finally
        {
            httpclient.close();
        }
    }
```

The HTTP client I use is `org.apache.http`

But unfortunately none of the above work properly. The system I'm integrating with keeps saying that `password` isn't provided and can't be `null`. Because of lack of documentation I have to understand if there are other ways to add content to body and it can be fixed on my side or whether their configuration is wrong.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I can test it using their service. Can't test with Swagger because `Token` updates quite often, and it returns me 401 (Unathorized)

On their site I can call the same method and it returns true/false as expected.

[image]

In `request payload` there it is - the `password`. But I don't know how to see it raw.

Is there any chrome extension to see/convert it to raw just like Wireshark does?

[image]

Comment: Were you able to verify using Swagger UI?

Comment: a. Can you try using content-type as text\plain as your request body is plain string rather than application/json

Comment: @Madhav Kumar Jha the server returns 500 Internal Server Error if I change it to text/plain

Comment: add a new header accept -- application/json as shown in browser console

Comment: Didn't seem to help :(

Comment: directly set content-type and charset on string entity.        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(password, "UTF-8");
        entity.setContentType("application/json");

Comment: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. still the same. I think I have a better idea, I should ask a person with access to resource to try catch packages in Wireshark. Then we will be able to customize needed standard hopefully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turned out that the password entity is supposed to be in double quotes :x

Only in this case it can "see" it..

Left me speechless needless to say

[image]